# Django - accidently removed superuser

Tags: django, django-users

I am using Django 1.4.5 and accidentally deleted the superuser. How can I recreate the superuser account for an existing project? I found tutorials that show to do it when initially setting up a project but can't figure out how to create a superuser for an existing project.

I did try `django-admin.py createsuperuser` in the terminal without any luck

I apprecite the time and feedback.

Comment: what does your "no luck" attempt report?

Comment: Unknown command: 'createsuperuser'

Comment: should I add the "username" and "password" to the command when submitting?

Comment: that won't change a bit, since createsuperuser cannot be found. Try out what Vladislav suggested :)

Comment: OK I figured it out. python manage.py createsuperuser

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can invoke this command through manage.py

```
./manage.py createsuperuser
```